# How to prevent font-size change of child element to stretch parent container in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a simple nav bar:

```
<nav>
 <a href="#">Home</a>
 <a href="#">About</a>
 <a href="#">Register</a>
</nav>
```

with following CSS for nav and a tags:

```
nav
{
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:150%;
    padding:2%;    
}
nav a
{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
    padding:2%;    
}
nav a:hover
{
    background-color:white;
    color:black;
    font-size:120%;            
}
```

It looks pretty much as I want it to, except that nav container stretches on hover, because font size is larger. How can I prevent nav from stretching?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an easier and prettier way. You should try this instead.

```
nav
{
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:150%;   
}
nav a
{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
    padding:2%;    
    display:inline-block;
}
nav a:hover
{
    background-color:white;
    color:black;
    transform: scale(1.2);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    -ms-transform:scale(1.2);
}
```

Comment: I tried it. Nothing happend... font is still the same. Was that scale(1.2) supposed to enlarge font on hover?

Comment: <a> is inline, you should make it inline-block, that will work

Comment: Thanks, now it works! The question now is, what's the better solution? line-height: 5%; or display:inline-block; with transforming?

Answer (score 1):

Adding a "line height" prevents the parent container from changing size.

```
nav a
{
    line-height: 5%;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
    padding:2%;    
}
```

Comment: THANKS! The exact thing I was looking for!

Comment: in which case you should upvote @Mayado20 's comment

Answer (score 0):

Use other values instead of %.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the code here: https://codepen.io/polinq/pen/xxbgZOM
So essentially I put a height on the nav element and removed padding. And centered it using flex.

```
nav
{
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:150%;

    height: 70px;
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

}
nav a
{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
    padding:2%;    
}
nav a:hover
{
    background-color:white;
    color:black;
    font-size:120%;  

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't use px, my project require from me to use only %